# OSGi bundle read config properties

Tags: spring, osgi

I have `config.properties` in my OSGi bundle. but the OSGi bundle can not read it.

```
Application context refresh failed (OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=dao, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml))
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

I am using Spring to read the `config.properties`

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="config.properties" />
</bean>
```

It seems like the OSGi only reads the `.xml` file.
    Does someone has any idea?

Comment: Your config.properties file is not found. Where is it located in your bundle?

Comment: I put it in the META-INF folder. and i want to find a way to put the config file outside the bundle and behavior like a global config setting. do it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the correct resource for your value property. 
There are some [built in implementations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-implementations), like:

- ClassPathResource: `value="classpath:/META-INF/config.properties"`
- FileSystemResource: `value="file:C:/foobar/config.properties"`

If you want to place the file outside the library you can use a system property (e.g. `-DpropertyFile=C:/loremIpsum/config.properties`) to specify the path, like

```
value="file:${propertyFile}"
```

since Spring 3.0.? even with default value

```
value="file:${propertyFile:C:/foobar/config.properties}"
```

(*Have a look at your OSGi framework on how to set a system property. I am also not sure if the ClassPathResource works well / is recommended in OSGi environments.*)